# Как сдвинуть recyclerView вниз?

Tags: android, kotlin

Может вы знаете как сделать подобную вещь как на gif? Я хочу чтобы мой recyclerView можно было сдвинуть вниз и показать кнопку под ним. Сейчас я выясняю что нам виден первый элемент списка, значит мы можем сдвигать его вниз, для этого добавляю слушатель касаний:

```
val first = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition
if (first < 1) { 
recyclerView.setOnTouchListener { v, event -> 
when(event?.action) {
MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> { 
startY = event.y // вычисляю точку первого касания по вертикали
}
MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVIE -> { 
// как сдвинуть вниз?
}
```

Пожалуйста, дайте совет как это можно сделать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант, можно сделать так

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Example"
        android:textSize="30dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Пример"
        android:textColor="#ff14be3c"
        android:textSize="30dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView2"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/app_name" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

И сам код

```
package com.example.testapp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.ClipData;
import android.content.ClipDescription;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.DragEvent;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView img;
    String msg = "LOG Drag&Drop";
    private android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams;

    final float[] dX = new float[2];
    final float[] dY = new float[2];
    boolean flag_open = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        img.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                ClipData.Item item = new ClipData.Item((CharSequence) v.getTag());
                String[] mimeTypes = {ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN};

                ClipData dragData = new ClipData(v.getTag().toString(), mimeTypes, item);
                View.DragShadowBuilder myShadow = new View.DragShadowBuilder(img);

                v.startDrag(dragData, myShadow, null, 0);
                return true;
            }
        });


        img.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                        dX[0] = view.getX() - event.getRawX();//позиция элемента
                        dY[0] = view.getY() - event.getRawY();
                        dX[1] = event.getRawX();//начальная точка касания
                        dY[1] = event.getRawY();
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        if (event.getRawY() + dY[0] > 0)
                            if ((!flag_open && event.getRawY() > dY[1])//движение вниз
                                    || (flag_open && event.getRawY() < dY[1]))//движение вверх
                                //сделаем перемещение
                                view.animate()
//                                .x(event.getRawX() + dX[0])
                                        .y(event.getRawY() + dY[0])
                                        .setDuration(0)
                                        .start();
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        //родительский компонент
                        LinearLayout layout = ((LinearLayout) view.getParent());
                        if ((!flag_open && event.getRawY() > 100 + dY[1])//движение вниз
                                || event.getRawY() + dY[0] + dY[1] < 200//доп условие при медленном движении вверх
                                || (flag_open && event.getRawY() < -100 + dY[1]))//движение вверх
                        {
                            //добавим элемент
                            if (!flag_open && layout.getChildCount() == 2) {

                                LinearLayout.LayoutParams params =
                                        new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                                                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                                //create a button
                                Button btnAdd = new Button(view.getContext());
                                btnAdd.setText("Add");
                                btnAdd.setLayoutParams(params);
//организуем перестановку элементов, вставленный станет первым
                                View v = (View) layout.getChildAt(0);
                                for (int i = 1; i < layout.getChildCount(); i++) {
                                    View v_current = (View) layout.getChildAt(i);
                                    if (i == 1) {
                                        layout.addView(btnAdd, 0);
                                        layout.removeViewAt(1);
                                        layout.addView(v, 1);
                                        flag_open = true;
                                    } else {
                                        layout.removeViewAt(i);
                                        layout.addView(v_current, i);
                                    }
                                }
                            } else if (flag_open && layout.getChildCount() == 3) {
                                //удаление элемента(сокрытие)

                                View v = (View) layout.getChildAt(1);
                                layout.removeViewAt(0);
//                            layout.addView(v, 0);
                                flag_open = false;
                            }
                            view.animate()
                                    //.x(event.getRawX() + dX)
                                    .y(0)
                                    .setDuration(0)
                                    .start();
                        } else if (!flag_open)
                            view.animate()
                                    //.x(event.getRawX() + dX)
                                    .y(0)
                                    .setDuration(0)
                                    .start();

                        break;
                    default:
                        return false;
                }
                return true;

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Решение может и не очень. Вместо создания кнопки можно сделать используя свойство Visibility например через GONE.
Элемент для сдвига выбрана картинка, тоже будет действовать и для других View
Вниз добавление, вверх удаление элемента(сокрытие)

Comment: Спасибо за такой прекрасный пример, это отлично работает